# API to CSV python script gets killed

Tags: python, python-3.x, zendesk, zendesk-api

This is a simple script that extracts data from api and writes it to csv however it always gets killed. There's no error description just "Killed" message.

I'm guessing it's due to some memory issues. Is there a way for this to be optimized where it doesn't eat up a lot of system memory? Data being processed is just around 100k.

```
with open('test4.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ticket_info, extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()

    for ticket in zenpy_client.search_export(updated_between=[start_date, end_date], type='ticket',form='1900000029568'):
        t = ticket.to_dict()
        writer.writerow(t)

    csvfile.close()
```

Edit: I tried to monitor the process and noticed that it gets killed when it consumes more than 85% of memory.

```
 PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR  S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 28789 root      20   0  7004m 6.7g 3584 R 50.0 85.2   2:48.29  python
```

Comment: _"Data being processed is just around 100k"_: 100k what? Rows? Bytes?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi rows and around 4mb total.

Comment: That's not a whole lot. Why do you think this is a memory problem? Have you done any [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), such as [stepping through your program with a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) to isolate the problem? Are you running this on your computer or on a remote server? Does it work anywhere else?

Comment: it runs on our remote server. it runs fine on my local pc.